# Alignment issue along with formatting the Total in the Pivot Table - Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

I am facing an issue in aligning the total row and I need to get look and feel like the image below .

I have tried the code below but I am not currently getting results in the required format.

Could anyone please let me know below if it is possible to get the results in the required format using Apache POI pivot table?

Below is the image which i am getting output.

[image: My Code OutPut]

My Output Pivot table structure.

[image]

Need required format as below.

[image]

```
     public class TestPivotTable
     {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        String[][] data = new String[][]{{"AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF","GGG","HHH"}, 
     {"TOM","DUMMY","VAL","1001683","Description1","27/04/2017","CAT","7,80,936.58"},
            {"TOM","DUMMY","VAL","1001695","Description2","27/04/2017","CAT","136.28"},
            {"HARRY","DUMMY1","VAL1","1001692","Description3","03/05/2017","CAT1","191468.21"},
            {"HARRY","DUMMY1","VAL1","1001698","Description4","04/05/2017","CAT1","10.11"}};

        XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("data");
        XSSFSheet pivot = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("summary");
        for(String[] dataRow : data){
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
            for(String dataCell : dataRow){
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
                cell.setCellValue(dataCell);
            }
        }
        XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();    
        CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();
        table.setDisplayName("table");
        cttable.setRef("A1:D4");
        cttable.setId(1);

        CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();
        columns.setCount(3);

        int g = 1;
        for (String colName : data[0]){
            CTTableColumn column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
            column.setId(++g);
            column.setName(colName);      
        }
      AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference("A1:H"+ (sheet.getLastRowNum() + 
      1),SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
      FileOutputStream fileOut=null;
      try {
        XSSFPivotTable pivotTable =  pivot.createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A1"), 
      sheet);

        pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setRowHeaderCaption("AAA");

        List<Integer> iterList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        iterList.add(0);
        iterList.add(1);
        iterList.add(2);
        iterList.add(3);
        iterList.add(4);
        iterList.add(5);
        iterList.add(6);

        for (Integer j : iterList) {

            pivotTable.addRowLabel(j);
            TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>();
            for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow()+1; r < 
       areaReference.getLastCell().getRow()+1; r++) {
                uniqueItems.add(sheet.getRow(r).getCell(j).toString());
            }
            System.out.println(uniqueItems);
            CTPivotField ctPivotField = 
       pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(j);
            int i = 0;
            for (String item : uniqueItems) {
                ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
                ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);


    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().
     getCacheFieldArray(j)
                .getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
                i++;
            }
            ctPivotField.setAutoShow(false);
            ctPivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false);
            ctPivotField.setCompact(false);
            ctPivotField.setSubtotalTop(true);
            if (ctPivotField.getDefaultSubtotal()) i++; 
            for (int k = ctPivotField.getItems().getItemList().size()-1; k >= i; k--) {
                ctPivotField.getItems().removeItem(k);
            }
            ctPivotField.getItems().setCount(i);

        }

        System.out.println("----end---");

        pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 7, "SUM");

        fileOut = new FileOutputStream("newoutputfile.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception While Creating Pivot Table"+e);
    }finally {
        fileOut.close();
        wb.close();
    }

    }
   }
```

Comment: Would help to show us what you get instead. Also I don't see any place where you would set any `CellStyle`/`DataFormat`

Comment: Hi, Actually i am getting in tree structure.

Comment: Can you show the window that lists `Filters`, `Columns`, `Rows` and `Values` in excel so we know which field goes where?

Comment: I just placed the output which i am getting. i am new to this Pivot table, so not getting the output with the format placed above.

Comment: Hi XtremeBaumer, added the pivot table filters,columns,rows and values structure

Comment: Include the `Pivot table structure` from your desired output as well

Comment: I tried but finding difficulties in achieving  that desired output format. Please let me know how to get that format.

Comment: As I said, "Include the Pivot table structure from your desired output as well". Right now I dont see any way to achiev the structure you want with a pivot table anyways. No matter if its via excel or apache poi

Comment: Since i am new to this pivot table ,so i am facing difficulties in achieving Pivot table structure for desired output in Excel only , so my question is that structure is not able to achieve through Pivot table?. .

Comment: Have you already created the structure with a pivot table manually?

Comment: No, i need to create the above desired structure in pivot table. But not able to achieve either with Pivot table Manually or by Apache POI. Please let me know is this achievable or not (either manually or code)?

Comment: If you can't create it manually, then apache poi can't create it either

Comment: since i am new to this Pivot table, that is the reason i don't know its achievable or not.I tried in my Way to achieve it manually but could not achieved it. So i don't know if i missed any steps in getting same format in pivot table manually. So please let me know this structure usually it is possible or not?.